# Custom abbreviation for citation in bibtex

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

When writing, I like to introduce an abbreviation for the whole citation. On the first instance, I would write "This is true as shown in (nbren12, et. al. 2012) (hereafter NB12)". In the subsequent usages, I would just say "This fact is true (NB12)". How can I implement this automatically using bibtex (or biblatex)?

This is similar but not identical to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47286/biblatex-abbreviating-authoring-organisations-in-citations).

Comment: That should be doable with `biblatex`? Do you use `biblatex`? If so what style do you use? If not, what style would you like to use (just a simple author-year style by the looks of it)?

Comment: I am using the springer svjour3 latex template which has natbib style commands. Not sure if I can use biblatex, but I would be interested in a biblatex solution either way.

Comment: I think you could just achieve it with `biblatex` and `alphabetic` style. Just check page 83-88 in the [manual](http://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) to see the various citation commands provided.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that then `biblatex` is out of the question, but I'll add a solution anyway. (Just an aside though: If you use the `svjour3` template, you probably ought to adhere to the bib/citation style of that template.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is described clearly in the [manual](ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natnotes.pdf) of `natbib` on page 3.

Use command:

```
\defcitealias{nbren12}{NB12}
```

After that, in addition to classic citing `\citet{}` or `\citep{}`, you can also use:

```
\citetalias{nbren12}
% or
\citepalias{nbren12}
```

### Example

In `example.tex` I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\begin{document}

\defcitealias{jd14}{JD14}

In text \citet{jd14}. Or in brackets \citep[][hereafter JD14]{jd14}.

Now I cite it in text as \citetalias{jd14} and in brackets \citepalias{jd14}.

\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

and in `mybib.bib` I have:

```
@article{jd14,
  author={Doe, J. and Smith, J. and Bar, F.},
  title={Some title},
  journal={Some journal},
  year={2014},
}
```

and the output is:

[image]

And if you want the alias to appear in e.g. italics, but not page numbers etc. you can write e.g. `\defcitealias{jd14}{{\itshape JD14}}`.

Comment: @egreg Can you, please, be more specific? I am used to do it, because I am looking for 99% of references at [ADS](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/physics_service.html). From there I can directly export the BibTeX entries and last names are _always_ inside `{}`. Thanks.

Comment: I simply don't know what's the rationale for this choice; there's no reason for it and it just makes BibTeX work more.

Comment: This is a great answer to the question as I wrote it. I was also thinking about mixing aliased and non aliased citations like (NB12; nbren12, et al 2014) using some \cite????{NB12,NB14} type command. (\citetalias{NB12};\citealp{NB14}) is too verbose for my tastes.

Answer (score 11):

[`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) has the built-in standard macro `shorthandintro` that can do this.
In the `.bib` file one will then add the `shorthand` field and give the short citation name there, like this

```
@article{jd14,
  author  = {Doe, J. and Smith, J. and Bar, F.},
  title   = {Some title},
  journal = {Some journal},
  year    = {2014},
  shorthand = {JD14},
}
```

The only thing that remains to be done is to make sure this macro is only called when it is appropriate. While there are some styles that already use `shorthandintro`, the plain `authoryear` and `authortitle` styles do not.

We well see how one can modify the `authoryear` so it uses the shorthand intro.
The default `cite` macro for `authoryear` can be found in `authoryear.cbx`.

The main citation part that is used if no shorthand is present can be out-sourced into a new macro `longcite`

```
\newbibmacro*{longcite}{%
  \ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}
    {\printnames{labelname}%
     \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
  \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}
```

Then the actual cite macro is changed to print a long citation and shorthand introduction at first cite (obviously the introduction is only printed if a shorthand is actually present) and the shorthand or long (normal) citation on subsequent citations.

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \ifciteseen
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
      {\usebibmacro{longcite}}
      {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
    {\usebibmacro{longcite}
     \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}}
```

In order to be able to use the `\ifciteseen` test, we will have to enable the `citetracker` (for example via `citetracker=true`).

Other citation styles use different `cite` macros and the modifications will have to be different then, also this modification does not currently work with `\textcite`.

MWE

```
\documentclass[british,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,citetracker=true]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{jd14,
  author  = {Doe, J. and Smith, J. and Bar, F.},
  title   = {Some Title},
  journal = {Some Journal},
  year    = {2014},
  shorthand = {JD14},
}
@article{jd13,
  author  = {Doe, J. and Smith, J. and Bar, F.},
  title   = {No shorthand here},
  journal = {Some Other Journal},
  year    = {2013},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newbibmacro*{longcite}{%
  \ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}
    {\printnames{labelname}%
     \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
  \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \ifciteseen
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
      {\usebibmacro{longcite}}
      {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
    {\usebibmacro{longcite}
     \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}}

\begin{document}
  \cite{jd14} again \cite{jd14} and one more time \cite{jd14}.

  Just for comparison \cite{jd13}.

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you prefer "hereafter `<key>`" to "henceforth cited as `<key>`", just add

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{citedas = {hereafter}}
```

to the preamble.

---

If you like Václav Pavlík's solution with `natbib`'s cite-alias function, you'll be delighted to hear that `biblatex`'s `natbib`compatibility mode (just pass `natbib=true` to the load-time options) also offers these features with (as far as I know) exactly the same syntax.

Comment: This is very slick! It even works for `\cite{jd13,jd14}`. Thanks