# Include citation alias (shorthand) in bibliography list

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

There are numerous questions which show how to use aliases in citations, [for example this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/203919/22806) (and I use the [MWE from the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203959/22806)).

[image]

**How can the shorthand itself (in this case `JD14`) be added to the bibliography for easier identification?**

i.e., I want the bibliography entry to end up as something like,

```
 Doe, J., Smith, J., and Bar, F. (2014) [JD14]. Some title. Some journal.
```

or even,

```
 [JD14]: Doe, J., Smith, J., and Bar, F. (2014). Some title. Some journal.
```

Comment: I think it should not be too complicated. But, usually, entries with shorthands are printed apart for easy identification, using `\printshorthands`, and then they reach the bibliography too. So, I ask, given this, do you really want the shorthand to go to the regular bibliography?

Comment: @gusbrs I actually had never heard of or seen that before - thanks, that's awesome!  Honestly, that solves my *immediate* problem, but I think some journals likely wouldn't allow such a split --- so perhaps it would still be useful information to include the abbreviate in the normal bibliography

Comment: @gusbrs actually, it looks like `\printshorthands` doesn't work with natbib.  Is there an equivalent?

Comment: I've been assuming you're using biblatex, given your tag. Biblatex has an option for compatibility with natbib commands, but is something different altogether. If you are using natbib as such, and can't use biblatex, my advice is really not very useful. But, in this case, I recommend you remove the `biblatex` tag of your question.

Comment: Do you even use `biblatex` as your tag suggests? If your code is indeed similar to the post you link to you are *not* using `biblatex`, that post uses `natbib` and BibTeX. Please retag your question in case you are not using `biblatex`. If you are indeed using `biblatex` note that `shorthand`s and citation alisases defined with `\defcitealias` are two completely different things.

Comment: @gusbrs sorry about that!