# Biblatex (apa): How to correctly use multiple shortauthors

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, acronyms

Using biblatex in combination with the apa style, I would like to cite references with institutional authors. As suggested in a [previous post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47291/118972) I use the `shortauthor` field to include abbreviations.

My issue occurs with references that include multiple institutional authors. Here I would like to use multiple entries in `shortauthor` as well. But the output I get looks not at all as expected.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
    @BOOK{ACER2015,
      author = {{Agency for the Cooperation of Energy Regulators} and {Council of European Energy Regulators}},
      shortauthor = {{ACER} and {CEER}},       
      title = {{ACER/CEER} Annual Report},
      year = {2015}
    }
    @TECHREPORT{CEER2014,
      author = {{Council of European Energy Regulators}},
      shortauthor = {{CEER}},
      title = {{CEER} Advice},
      year = {2014}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backref=false,style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
First reference produces output with unexpected format \parencite{ACER2015}.

Second reference looks correct \parencite{ACER2015}.

A third reference to one of the previous authors produces full output \parencite{CEER2014}.
\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:
[image]

The expected output would have been:
[image]

How can I make use of the `shortauthor` field to achieve the expected outcome?

Comment: Imho the code of biblatex-apa doesn't expect multiple shortauthors. Make a feature request: https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/

Comment: As biblatex seems to support multiple shortauthors, is there an alternative style that appropriately makes use of such entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really possible in any easy way because you have to match the shortauthor to the relevant author. It would be possible using the annotation feature but this is a bit overkill for putting into the APA style. Isn't this acceptable:?

```
@BOOK{ACER2015,
  author = {{Agency for the Cooperation of Energy Regulators} and {Council of European Energy Regulators}},
  shortauthor = {{ACER/CEER}},       
  title = {{ACER/CEER} Annual Report},
  year = {2015}
}
```

Comment: This is the only solution that came to my mind as well; I just thought there would be another option. But that doesn't seem to be the case.