# Citing and references (APA7 Style): Cite only first author and abbreviation of groups

Tags: bibliographies

I write a thesis, use zotero and LaTeX with VS Code, citing style is APA Style 7th edition. According to the table "Multiple authors in APA in-text citations" in [Scribbr](https://www.scribbr.com/apa-style/in-text-citation/) I can abbreviate group names and I have to list only the first author followed by "et al." if more than two authors given. But it does not work. How to accomplish this?

My preamble looks like this:

```
(...)

% APA Style for BibTeX
\usepackage[style=apa,natbib=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}

(...)
```

For citing in text I generally use:

```
\citet[p.~100]{dellermann2019}
```

or

```
\citep[p.~100]{dellermann2019}
```

It gives me an output like this:

> They acknowledge this as an initial taxonomy (Dellermann, Calma, et al., 2019, p. 274-p. 27)

Here, it should output: They acknowledge this as an initial taxonomy (Dellermann et al., 2019, p. 274-p. 27)

Summarizing:
What I want is:

> "[1st_author] et al. [year]".

But my code give me the output

> "[1st_author], [2nd_author], et al., [year]"

2. I want the author (which is a group) to be abbreviated in subsequent citations. It does not work either. Always the full name is output in the text. There is this [document](https://publications.jrc.ec.europa.eu/repository/handle/JRC120469), published by the Joint Research entre (JRC).

The out put is always (first and subsequent citations) using \citep command:

> (Joint Research Centre, 2020, p. 5).

I want it to be listed with full name followed by abbreviation like so in the **first** listing in the text:

> (Joint Research Centre [JRC], 2020)

and like so in the **subsequent** listings in the text:

> (JRC, 2020)

Please see the table "Multiple authors in APA in-text citations" in [Scribbr](https://www.scribbr.com/apa-style/in-text-citation/). There is a listing for narrative and parenthetical citation (APA 7 Style).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Have a look at the [`maxcitenames` and `mincitenames` keys](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1557/106162) but note [these keys can be overriden in favour of unambiguous citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/106162). Is this what you mean by abbreviating an author? Otherwise I'm not sure what you're looking for there, could you give an example?

Comment: Hello! That is not what I want. The references list works so far. My problem atm is citing within the text. APA 7 style wants to have this form for more than two authors: "[1st_author] et al. [year]". But my code give me the output "[1st_author], [2nd_author], et al., [year]". I will edit that in my post, also the group issue.

Comment: That wasn't the best link as it focuses on the bibliography, but `mincitenames`/`maxcitenames` control the number of names shown by `\cite`-type commands [it's definitely what you want for your first point](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69030/106162).

Comment: Your second question wants the [`shortauthor` field in the bib entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47291/106162).

Comment: 1) now i know why two authors are output, because LaTeX tries to avoid ambiguity, because two sources have the same first author and the same year. I do not know if APA 7 
2) Is there an option to do that automated with zotero? AFAIK i cannot add a field "shortauthor" in zotero I do not want to do this manually all the time, since I atm extend the references